# Convert a org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter to a org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a custom `org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter` written to be used by [spring-amqp](https://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/) but now we're moving to [spring cloud stream](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/) which uses another MessageConverter (`org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter`).

So is there a way to convert from a Spring AMQP MessageConverter (`org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter`) to a Spring Cloud Stream MessageConverter (`org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter`)?

If not, is there a way to convert between a `org.springframework.amqp.core.Message` to a `org.springframework.messaging.Message` and vice versa so that I can reuse my customer message converter written for Spring AMQP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the nature of your customization?

In Spring Cloud Stream, on the consumer side, the AMQP message is already converted to a messaging `Message<?>` before the converters are consulted to convert the `byte[]` payload (the AMQP message `body()`) to the required type.

`MessageProperties` are mapped to `Message<?>` headers.

On the outbound side, the converter must create a `byte[]` payload.

Converters in SCSt are independent of the transports (RabbitMQ, Kafka etc) so you can change the binder without rewriting any code.

So you will need to port your logic to a messaging converter.